# Julia: getting subarray with multiple Boolean comparisons

Tags: indexing, boolean, julia

How can we do the following Matlab code in Julia?

```
A=rand(4); 
A(:,A(1,:)>0.7)
```

I've tried:

```
A=rand(4,4);
A[:,A[1,:].>0.7]
```

Which results in: ERROR: `getindex` has no method matching getindex(::Array{Float64,2}, ::UnitRange{Int64}, ::BitArray{2})

Comment: You tried [...] but what problem did you experience? Please edit your question and add some details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

** **EDIT** **

Julia has gone through many changes in 3.5 years and now the OP's question is moot.  That style of array indexing now works.

See the current [Julia Docs on Array Indexing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#man-supported-index-types-1) for the full list of methods.

** **Original, for the History Books** **

In Julia, [`Array`indexing](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#man-array-indexing) needs to be done with a `Vector` (here with a boolean vector).

One way to accomplish what you want is to use the `vec` function:

```
julia> A = rand(4,4)
4x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0253057  0.748903  0.633581  0.796249
 0.25894    0.330299  0.668624  0.723979
 0.884216   0.521359  0.957751  0.207386
 0.862909   0.286173  0.592699  0.965437

julia> A[:, vec(A[1,:] .> 0.7)]
4x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.748903  0.796249
 0.330299  0.723979
 0.521359  0.207386
 0.286173  0.965437
```

Another way is:

```
julia> A[:, A[1,:][:] .> 0.7]
4x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.748903  0.796249
 0.330299  0.723979
 0.521359  0.207386
 0.286173  0.965437
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the extra dimension in the indexing array.

```
A=rand(4,4);
A[:,squeeze(A[1,:], 1).>0.7]
```

Comment: The 2nd line gives: ERROR: squeezed dims must all be size 1
 in squeeze at abstractarray.jl:137