# Obtaining columns of a matrix satisfying multiple booleans in Julia

Tags: python, indexing, boolean, julia, scientific-computing

I am trying to obtain only those columns of a matrix that satisfy two or more boolean conditions. More specifically, I am trying to find only those eigenvectors of a matrix based on certain constraints on the eigenvalues.

In python3.x I would do :

```py
def get_special_vectors(A:np.ndarray,thresold1:float,thresold2:float) -> np.ndarray:
   eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(A)
   eigvec = eigvec[:,np.array(eigval >= threshold1) & np.array(eigval <= thresold2)]
return eigvec
```

However in Julia, I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331769/julia-getting-subarray-with-multiple-boolean-comparisons) post but I seem to be messing up the AND (&) operator. I'm trying the following that results in a `MethodError`:

```
eigvec = eigvec[:,vec(evalA .< 1.0) & vec(evalA .> 0)]
```

I'll be glad if someone can share any useful suggestions or any kind of help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should also broadcast the `&`:

```
vec(evalA .< 1.0) .& vec(evalA .> 0)
```

I can't say for sure if it will solve your problem since you didn't give a complete example

You also might want to look at `eachrow` and `eachcol`

Answer (score 2):

You need to broadcast also `&` so write `.&` instead like this:

```
eigvec[:,vec(evalA .< 1.0) .& vec(evalA .> 0)]
```

however in this case the following should also just work:

```
eigvec[:,vec(0 .< evalA .< 1.0)]
```

(I do not see what `evalA` is, so it is hard to tell if `vec` is actually required in your code - I assume that it is required so I left it)

Comment: Hi! This solves the issue. Thank you!
`eval` refers to the vector of eigenvalues.